# Candlestick chart on bitcoinwisdom

Tags: charts, financial, candlestick-chart

Im in need for good candlestick chart for my web app and chart at http://bitcoinwisdom.com/ is really what Im looking for. I like the way you can zoom and move with it. Is it possible to figure out what they are using or do you think they made it up on their own? If so with what tools? Another amazing charting can be found here https://www.tradingview.com/e/ these two sites have even better charting than some desktop apps and I wanna know how they did it.

Answer (score 7):

In searching the bitcoinwisdom's forums I found a couple posts asking for the exact same thing.  In fact, I stumbled upon your SO post here looking for the same thing.

According to those forum posts' responses they used [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/) with the rest being custom code.  Unfortunately for us as their implementation is very impressive!  View source on the page and look for the JS files they are referencing.  The code is obfuscated and minified so porting it will be very difficult.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @T.S. - Really my response was to hopefully assist user1816019 in discovering 'how they did it'.  No new question here :) but thanks for helping!

Comment: d3js uses svg , not a great idea for plotting real time candlesticks